# Numpy - why Fortran memory layout is faster than C layout when reading row-wise

Tags: python, numpy

I've been struggling to understand the differences between Fortran order and C order in numpy. From what I undestand, in Fortran-style order elements from the same columns are next to each other in memory, while in C-style order the same holds for elements from the same row. So, logically thinking, if I read 2d array row-wise it should be faster using C order than F order. But the following code gives opposite result:

```
import numpy as np
import time

def timer(func):
    def inner_timer(c):
        start = time.time()
        func(c)
        return time.time()-start
    return inner_timer

@timer
def foo(c):
    x = np.arange(1000000).reshape((1000, -1), order=c)
    print(x.flags['C_CONTIGUOUS'])
    print(x.flags['F_CONTIGUOUS'])
    for i in range(1000):
        for _ in range(1000):
            for j in range(1000):
                x[i,j]

print(f"C order: {foo('C')}", end='\n\n')
print(f"F order: {foo('F')}")
```

Here is output:

```
True
False
C order: 96.99969506263733

False
True
F order: 93.83203744888306
```

Why is it happening? Maybe reshape doesn't change layout of data in memory, but then why in one case C_CONTIGUOUS is true, but in the other F_CONTIGUOUS is true? Because if I understand correctly, these two flags describe which memory layout is used.

Thank you in advance for all the answers

Comment: Indexing to individual elements from Python code is expected to be rather slow in any case, and the actual time for the memory access should be completely negligible compared to the several layers of Python function calls performed for each access.

Comment: Note that this code is not a good way of benchmarking code. You should run the code many times and build averages, preferably using the `timeit` module. Expect a few percent of error margin anyway, so I don't think you found a significant difference here.

Comment: For what it's worth, I can't reproduce your result – for me Fortran order is slightly slower, but probably still within error margins, so let's just consider both approaches equally slow, just as expected.

Comment: In that case, is there any scenario when it is better to use F order than C order?. Because performance is basically the same in both cases

Comment: This is not how Numpy is supposed to be used. I suggest reading some basic introduction into Numpy. Iterating over Numpy arrays using Python loops is slow. You need vectorized operations instead.

Comment: I am also unable to reproduce the problem. When you compare two codes, you need to consider the *standard deviation* of the timings and so run the code multiple times to do so. With only the mean time, this is impossible to say that one code is faster than another. For example your processor may work at low frequency for the fist code and high frequency for the second (due to a slow wake up). This is why good benchmark interleave the execution of compared code.